# Struts 2 select tag - Using the tag (with the same list) multiple times on a page does not work

Tags: struts2, html-select

I need to be able to use the same drop down list multiple times on a page. The first time i use the 'list' on the select tag, it works fine. The same list does not populate the second select tag i use it on. Here are the details.

In the action class, i populate the ArrayList containing values i need to populate the select tag.

```
setNames(new SomeDAO().getNames());
```

In the JSP

```
<s:select list="names"  
id="nameList"
listKey="nameId"
listValue="userName"                      
/>
```

This select list populates just fine. If I use the following select tag on the same page (using the same list), it fails to print.

```
<s:select list="names"                                                      
      id="rName"                                 
      listKey="nameId"
      listValue="userName" />
```

If i replace the 'list' above with #{'test':'test'} (hardcoded list), the tag shows up fine. Looks like the property i set in the Action is getting cleared after the first use. Is that whats happening or am i doing something wrong? I get an 'IllegalStateException: Response already committed' error

Edit 1:
setNames() is used in the action method that deals with the JSP page. It is a simple getter function.
In the JSP, here is what i have.

```
        <tr>
          <td align="left" class="td-plain">Add New:</td>
          <td class="td-plain">
                    <s:select list="names"  
                              id="addNameID"                                                    
                              name="addUserNameID"
                              listKey="reinsId"
                              listValue="reinsName"                   
                                  headerKey=""
                              headerValue="--User Name--"
                     />
          </td>
          <td class="td-plain"><input id="addTreatyNumber" type="text" /></td>  
          <td class="td-plain"><input id="addReinsPercentage" type="text" /></td>
          <td class="td-plain"><input id="addFlatDollarRetentionAmt" type="text" /></td>            
          <td class="td-plain">
              <%if(finance){ %>
                   <input type="button" class="greyButton" value="Add" onclick="addReinsInfo()"/>
              <%}else{ %>
         None
         <%} %> 
         </td>

     </tr>
```

and then later down on that page, i have

```
<tr id='<s:property value="caseGroupId"/>:<s:property value="treatyId"/>'>
        <td class="td-plain"><input type='checkbox' id='<s:property value="caseGroupId"/>:<s:property value="treatyId"/>'/></td> 
        <td class="td-plain">
                            <s:select list="names"                                                      
                              id="rName"            
                              name="dName"                   
                              listKey="reinsId"
                              listValue="reinsName"                   
                              headerKey=""
                              headerValue="--User Name--"

                             />

        </td>
        <td class="td-plain_"><s:textfield id="tNumber" value="%{treatyNumber}"/></td>           
        <td class="td-plain_"><s:textfield id="tPercentage" value="%{reinspercentage}"/></td>
        <td class="td-plain_"><s:textfield id="rAmount" value="%{flatDollarRetentionAmt}"/></td>                        
       <td class="td-plain"><input type="button" value="Delete" class="greyButton"/></td>   
      </tr>
```

If I change the 'list' in the second tag to

```
list="#{'Test':'Test'}"
```

the tag shows up fine. Please let me know if i can provide any further info.

Edit 2: I was able to get this to work by setting the drop down list values to the session.

Comment: The error makes no sense w/o knowing more about the action. *Where* in the action do you call `setNames(...)`? Is there anything beyond simple getter functionality in `getNames()`?

Comment: Also show the whole JSP, doing things the typical struts2 way would make getting such an error very challenging. Are you using scriptlets or a custom result type?

Comment: I've added more info.

Answer (score 0):

As asked by @Dave and @Quaternion, post the relevant Java/JSP code.

But until then... I've noted that you are not using `name` attribute in Struts `Select`s;

while you can refer multiple times from different tags to the same source (the `list` attribute), to populate the `Select` from the same list of objects, you should instead specify a different `name` for each one, to define which variable (sent back to the Action) contains the selected value of which `Select`;

this may not be the answer to the current question but it will show up to you soon.